# How to make a loading screen that ignores lazy loading images

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

I have a loading screen that hides on the event window load.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    Loader.classList.add("hide")
});
```

but I also have Images that are set to `loading="lazy"`, I am trying to hide the loading screen when everything except the images has loaded.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Insert the lazyloading of images after load then

Comment: Can you clarify what you consider "loaded" to be? If you just want to execute your script when the DOM is ready, use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

Comment: MDN states that, "The load event fires when the eagerly-loaded content has all been loaded; at that time, it's entirely possible (or even likely) that there may be lazily-loaded images that are within the visual viewport that haven't yet loaded." 
So I don't think loading="lazy" will impact `onLoad` 
Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading#images_and_iframes

Comment: @ScottMarcus I mean when all the elements and images(except with the `loading= "lazy"` attribute) are loaded I want to hide the Loader, it is okay if the images with the `loading= "lazy"` attribute haven't loaded yet.

Comment: @naveen Thanks that does work, even though I would have preferred to use event listener, window.onLoad hides it before lazy-loading images have loaded in. I am not sure why `onLoad` works and `addEventListener("load"` doesn't but it's good enough.

Comment: I tested this further and it seems when I network throttle using firefox's in-built tools, it doesn't work then...